# Waiting for submodules initialization in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization

I have app in which I'm starting few threads, each with one submodule.
After thread is started submodule is initializing and then running.

```
public class MySubmoduleThread extends Thread {
    ...
    private MySubmodule mSubmodule;
    ...
    @Override
    public final void run() {
        mSubmodule.initialize();
        mSubmodule.run();
    }
}
```

These threads are started on application `onCreate`. What is the simples way to wait until all submodules are initialized?

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
        mSubmoduleThread1.start();
        mSubmoduleThread2.start();
        ...
        mSubmoduleThreadN.start();
        --> waitSomehowUntilAllSubmodulesAreInitialized
        ...
    }
```

Of course I can edit `MySubmoduleThread` code to add something between `mSubmodule.initialize();` and `mSubmodule.run();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider not waiting at all. Blocking the main thread is not a good idea. The place that uses the submodules can probably access them asynchronously and wait in case it needs to.

Otherwise use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), .. from the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

```
public class MySubmoduleThread extends Thread {
    ...
    private MySubmodule mSubmodule;
    private CountDownLatch mLatch; // shared latch object accross tasks
    public MySubModuleThread(CountDownLatch latch) {
        mLatch = latch;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public final void run() {
        mSubmodule.initialize();
        mLatch.countDown(); // count 1 down
        mSubmodule.run();
    }
}

public class MyApp extends Application {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        int nrOfTasks = /* N */;
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(nrOfTasks);
        mSubmoduleThread1 = new SubModuleThread(latch);
        mSubmoduleThread2 = new SubModuleThread(latch);
        ...
        mSubmoduleThread1.start();
        mSubmoduleThread2.start();
        ...
        mSubmoduleThreadN.start();

        latch.await(); // wait that countdown reaches 0 (needs some try catch)

    }
```